# Why is my SVG image not displaying when I import it into my Icon object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

Why is my SVG image not displaying when I import it into my Icon object?

Feel free to reply if you need any other coding from me.

Full path copied from VS code when I right clicked on my svg image. `/Users/myName/Documents/GitHub/GitHub_REPO/repo_name/src/images/svg-1.svg`

[output of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuaeL.png)

```
export const ServicesIcon = styled.div`
height: 160px;
width:160px;
margin-bottom:10px;
`;
```

Comment: Can you post your `ServicesIcon` component too?

Comment: What does it display when you `console.log(Icon1)`? Also what `ServicesIcon` component do when you pass src prop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `ServicesIcon` is not an image but a `div` which doesn't have an `src` attribute so the src in `<ServicesIcon src={Icon1} />` won't do anything.

Either change the `div` to `img`, or if you want to keep the `div` you can use the `src` prop as a URL for the `background-image`.